# Adding SignalR in WebApi Project

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I need to integrate SignalR into my application. We have a WebApi Project and AngularJs applications hosted separately on Azure App Service. I was trying to install SingalR using NuGet package but it installing jQuery package which we don't require on WebApi project. How we make these two applications talk to each other in real time using SignalR.

Thanks

Comment: Install the correct package.  You're installing the package that includes server and client components.

Comment: can you name down the package for Client and Server

Comment: Technically putting jQuery in won't *hurt* anything; but you just want .Sever IIRC

Comment: but why we need js files on server side until it not required.

Comment: You don't.  If you don't want the JS components, you're installing the wrong package.  "This package pulls in the server components and JavaScript client required to use SignalR in an ASP.NET application."  Notice that it has two dependencies?  One for `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS` and the other for.... `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb`.

Comment: well, do we really need jQuery in webapi project ??

Comment: No, it just doesn't affect anything. To avoid them just use the second package Amy listed

Comment: okay , and for angular project Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS will be the correct one...right ?